# What will be the SQL trigger of this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables, requirement, selloffer and tradeleads. Tradelead is a table which holds the common entities of earlier two tables.

```
Schema of requirement:
  reqId, name, description, posteddate, companyid, cat1,cat2,cat3 ....

Schema of selloffer:
  sellid, name, description, posteddate, companyid, cat1,cat2,cat3 ....

Schema of tradelead: 
  id, name, description, posteddate, companyid, cat1,cat2,cat3, typeid
```

here in the tradelead i am using typeid to distinguish btween buy and sell. It its buy then 1 will get inserted alongwith the data else 2.

So what will be mine trigger for the above scenario?

**Scenario:
whenever a row is either inserted into requirements or selloffers, a row will also get created into the tradeleads tables, using the above mentioned columns.Mean to say when a row is created in requirement it also get created in TradeLead with type id =1 and if it is creating in selloffers , the tradelead will get populated with type=2 and rest same.
I hope , i am clear now**

Comment: What specifically is supposed to be inserted and from what tables into which tables? It's a simple `INSERT` trigger, but it depends on the criteria and where you are inserting into.

Comment: Is the id column in tradelead an IDENTITY column, or is it the reqId or sellid of the source row?

Comment: first col with id as suffix are peimary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.requirment_insert
ON dbo.requirment
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.tradelead(id, name, ..., typeid)
      SELECT reqId, name, ..., 1
      FROM inserted;
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.selloffer_insert
ON dbo.selloffer
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.tradelead(id, name, ..., typeid)
      SELECT sellid, name, ..., 2
      FROM inserted;
END
GO
```